# Using "même si" for real event?

Tags: conjonctions

Can "même si" be used with a real event with a similar meaning as "bien que" or "quoique"? According to the site listed below, the answer seems to be no.

> On doit éviter d’employer de façon interchangeable les locutions bien que et même si. La locution conjonctive bien que introduit une concession qui vise une situation passée ou présente, tandis que même si sert à introduire une hypothèse ou une éventualité. « Bien que l’avocat ait déposé cette pièce dans les délais impartis, le juge n’a pas pu en tenir compte. » « Même si l’avocat déposait cette pièce dans les délais impartis, le juge ne pourrait pas en tenir compte. »

However, a poster on [another site](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic43395-difference-entre-meme-si-et-bien-que.html) asserts that "même si" can be used in the following sentence.

> Nous continuons à marcher 2 h chaque jour **même si** nous sommes âgés maintenant.

Which one is right?

Reference: http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/juridi/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_m&page=9T4n--cTWlCI.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### general

On wiktionary :

> [**même si**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%AAme_si) \mɛm si\
>
> - Conjonction indiquant que la proposition qui précède est également vraie quand la proposition qui suit est vraie.
>
> [**bien que**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bien_que) \bjɛ̃ kə\
>
> - Conjonction de subordination introduisant une concession.

There is no particular link between those two and even if sometimes they could be interchanged, it is not a general rule.

---

#### tense

Beware about tense :

> [*même si*:] Cette conjonction est normalement précédée du conditionnel (quand on parle du passé) ou du futur.

while

> [*bien que* :] En français moderne, cette locution concessive réclame le subjonctif. C’était beaucoup moins le cas en moyen français.
> Le verbe être et son sujet peuvent être omis dans la subordonnée si le sujet est le même que dans la principale.

Your particular sentence :

> Nous continuons à marcher 2 h chaque jour *même si* nous sommes âgés maintenant.

is

> Nous continuons à marcher 2 h chaque jour *bien que* nous **soyons** âgés maintenant.

Comment: I agree, I'll just add that with your definitions "Bien que" can, most of the time, be switched with "même si" when "même si" can, only sometimes, be switched with "bien que". And in speaken French, "bien que" is not that used.

Comment: @JulianColin Bien que je ne sois pas d'accord avec vous, j'ai bien pris note de votre commentaire.

Comment: J'aimerais bien savoir, pourquoi n'êtes vous pas d'accord ?

Comment: @JulianColin Cf. ta dernière phrase ;)

Comment: Ah, c'est peut être une question d'âge, mais personnellement mon entourage et moi n'utilisons presque jamais "bien que", par contre à l'écrit ou dans des émissions formelles, c'est très répandu. C'était vraiment dans le sens casual ^^